# Inverse cot in C#

Tags: c#, math

We know that the inverse of `tan` is `Math.Atan`, what about the inverse of cot? `cot(x)` is defined as

```
cot(x)=1/tan(x)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Inverse Cotangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html). For some values, the inverse would be `atan(1/x)`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two commonly used conventions for the inverse of Cotangent, since e.g. cot(1) = cot(1-pi). It is important to think through which definition one wishes to use.

1. Let arccot(x) match atan(1/x), with values between -pi/2 and pi/2. This gives a discontinuity at 0 (jumps from -pi/2 to pi/2). This is the convention used in Greg Hew's answer.

   [image: arccot with values between -pi/2 and pi/2, image from Wolfram MathWorld]

   ```
   public static double Acot(double x)
   {
       return (x < 0 ? -Math.PI/2 : Math.PI/2) - Math.Atan(x);
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   public static double Acot(double x)
   {
       return x == 0 ? 0 : Math.Atan(1/x);
   }
   ```
2. Let arccot(x) be a continuous function with values between 0 and pi. This is the convention used in Daniel Martin's answer.

   [image: arccot with values between 0 and pi, image from Wikipedia]

   ```
   public static double Acot(double x)
   {
       return Math.PI/2 - Math.Atan(x);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative for inverse of cotangent is `Math.PI/2 - Math.Atan(x)` which has the advantage of working properly when `x` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Math.Atan2** method as Inverse cot like below without checking zero value.

```
var value = Math.Atan2(1,cotValue);
```